# How to generate razorpay order id in the backend with android?

Tags: razorpay

I am using razorpay to implement online payment in the android app. i want to generate order id in the backend. How to do that?

```
public void startPayment() {
    Checkout checkout = new Checkout();
    final Activity activity = this;
    try {
        JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
        options.put("name", "abc");
        options.put("description", "Order #123456");
        //options.put("order_id", "order_9A33XWu170gUtm");
        options.put("currency", "INR");
        /*
          Amount is always passed in currency subunits
          Eg: "500" = INR 5.00
         */
        options.put("amount", 500*100);
        checkout.open(activity, options);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Timber.e("Error in starting Razorpay Checkout", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you're using Java it's recommended to use our Java SDK as a backend platform to generate order_id's and pass the same to your client-side UI to make the payment for that order. 
Refer the doc for integrating the Java SDK for creating orders [here](https://razorpay.com/docs/server-integration/java/usage/#orders)

Comment: i am not able to initialize RazorpayClient .

Answer (score 0):

Add another library to the project in `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.24' // is the latest version
    implementation "com.razorpay:razorpay-java:1.4.3" 
}
```

Now, the Razorpay client will be initialized:

```
RazorpayClient razorpay = new RazorpayClient(AppConfigSettings.Razor_Key, AppConfigSettings.Razor_Secret);

JSONObject orderRequest = new JSONObject();
orderRequest.put("amount", 5000); // amount in the smallest currency unit
orderRequest.put("currency", "INR");
//orderRequest.put("receipt", "order_rcptid_13");
orderRequest.put("receipt", rcpt);

Order order = razorpay.orders.create(orderRequest);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(order));
order_Id = jsonObject.getString("id");
System.out.println("ID formed is " + order_Id); and to fetch the order ID from the response
```